# What's the consequence of telling isomorphic graphs apart for the complexity class of a graph property?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, graph-isomorphism

A graph  property is  a  class  of  graphs  with  the property  that  any  two  isomorphic  graphs  either  both  belong  to  the  class,  or both do not belong to it.

A graph invariant is any function $S:G \to {R}^+_{0}$ such that for isomorphic graphs $G,G'$, i.e. $G \sim G'$, holds $S(G)=S(G')$.

If there is now an algorithm being able to tell isomorphic graphs apart, $S(G) \neq S(G') \Leftrightarrow G \not\sim G$,
that is between $P$ and $NP$, how can I then interpret that a graph property is in $NP$?

I am somehow lacking here a piece that telling graphs apart is between $P$ and $NP$, and hence any graph property should be bound by such a complexity, and still having properties in $NP$.

Comment: Could you give an example of such an invariant?

Comment: The graph density. $G \sim G'$, hence they have the same number of edges.

Comment: But there are graphs which are not isomorphic and still have the same number of edges, hence $G \not\sim G'$ does not imply $|E(G)| \neq |E(G')|$.

Comment: Sure, there are also graphs $G \not\sim G'$ such that $|E(G)|=|E(G')|$. 
However, if two graphs are isomorphic, for an assignment $S$ being well-defined as a property, $G$ and $G'$ must get assigned the same value, $S(G)=S(G')$.

Comment: I might missinterpreting notation but the claim $S(G) \neq S(G') \iff G \not\sim G$ is false for the provided reason.

Comment: This is not meant to be a graph invariant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120836/discussion-between-m-noll-and-david-scholz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even being *instantly* able to tell whether two graphs are isomorphic doesn't give you an obvious test for some graph properties.

Consider the property "$G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle": testing for this is one of the classic NP-complete problems. You *could* try to test for it by testing if $G$ is isomorphic to any graph on a list of all $n$-vertex graphs with a Hamiltonian cycle. However, there are exponentially many graphs on any such list. So you will not get an efficient algorithm in this way.